# how to send Formdata through AJAX or serialized form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to know what is wrong in this code that prevent sending the `$_POST` of multiple input file.

here the view:

```
      <?php form_open_multipart('Emails/inbox',array('id'=>'fileupload')?>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 r-message-left">

                        <div class="block col-xs-12">
                                <div id="files1" class="col-xs-12 files">
                                    <ul id="sortable" class="fileList">
                                    <span>Uploaded files</span>
                                    </ul>

                                <label class="button" for="images"> Upload</label>
                                <input type="file" id="images" name="files1" multiple="multiple" />

                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <table class="zebra-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <button type="submit" style="height: 35px;width: 78px;" name="send" id="uploadBtn" value="1" class="btn btn-success m-t-20"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> send</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and the script which i put it in the footer and the idea is to remove selected files or images from the multiple input file before saving it .. it doesn't actually remove it from the queue as I knew that it is impossible .. i just send the files that i want to save through the `script` then do the thing, then send it to the controller to save .. but `formData` doesn't send anything!!

```
<script>
$.fn.fileUploader = function(filesToUpload, sectionIdentifier) {
  var fileIdCounter = 0;

  this.closest(".files").change(function(evt) {
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
      fileIdCounter++;
      var file = evt.target.files[i];
      var fileId = sectionIdentifier + fileIdCounter;

      filesToUpload.push({
        id: fileId,
        file: file
      });

      var removeLink = "<img src='" + URL.createObjectURL(file) + "' style='width:100%;'/><span class=\"removeFile closebtn\" style='cursor: pointer' data-fileid=\"" + fileId + "\"><h6>x</h6></span>";

      output.push('<li class="ui-state-default" data-order=0 data-id="' + file.lastModified + '">', removeLink, '</li> ');
    };

    $(this).children(".fileList")
      .append(output.join(""));

    //reset the input to null - nice little chrome bug!
    evt.target.value = null;
  });

  $(this).on("click", ".removeFile", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fileId = $(this).parent().children("span").data("fileid");

    // loop through the files array and check if the name of that file matches FileName
    // and get the index of the match
    for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++i) {
      if (filesToUpload[i].id === fileId)
        filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
    }

    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  this.clear = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++i) {
      if (filesToUpload[i].id.indexOf(sectionIdentifier) >= 0)
        filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
    }

    $(this).children(".fileList").empty();
  }

  return this;
};

(function() {
  var filesToUpload = [];

  var files1Uploader = $("#files1").fileUploader(filesToUpload, "files1");

  $("#uploadBtn").click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0, len = filesToUpload.length; i < len; i++) {
      //alert(filesToUpload[i].file);
      formData.append("files", filesToUpload[i].file);
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Emails/inbox',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        //alert(data)
        files1Uploader.clear();
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert("ERROR - " + data.responseText);
      }
    });

  });
})()
</script>
```

my controller

```
 public function inbox(){
    $this->load->model('email/Email');

    if($this->input->post('send') == 1){
        var_dump($_FILES,$_POST);die;
        $email_id = $this->Email->insert();
      }
     }
```

I should see `post` named `files` .. but as i said nothing
help.

Comment: Not sure if this will be of any help but try doing this `url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Emails/inbox'` --> `url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Emails/inbox"`?

Comment: you miss understood, the url ajax is just fine the result of `var_dum()` is every single `post` in the form except the multiple input file.

Answer (score 2):

To send multiple files, they either have to have different names, or the names should end with `[]` so that PHP will put them into an array. So try:

```
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0, len = filesToUpload.length; i < len; i++) {
    //alert(filesToUpload[i].file);
    formData.append("files[]", filesToUpload[i].file);
}
```

File inputs are not put into `$_POST`, they're only in `$_FILES`.

Comment: I just tried it but still give me the same answer 

 'files1' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
empty array

Comment: Put back `e.preventDefault()`. You're seeing the result of normal form submission, not the AJAX submission.

Comment: `files1` comes from the form, `formData` calls it `files`.

Comment: Or change the button to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: I just did what you just proposed .. I putted back `e.preventDefault()` and also  changed the button to` type="button"` .. when i click the `button` it doesn't go to the `controller` at all and can't execute `var_dump` to see the `$_POST` result.

Comment: Check the browser console to see if there are errors. And use the Network tab to see if the AJAX request is being sent, and what response is being received.

Comment: thanks for the tip .. at first i didn't have a clue of what you said about console or network, but after a very quick search I got it.
It did send the post.
thanks again very much.

Comment: the AJAX was running just fine, till this morning.
i don't know what happened 
`POST http://localhost/refaq/Emails/inbox 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6 `
this error just came up in console 
HELP!

Comment: That's a problem with your server script, check the server error log.